# Getting module names from unittest tests in python

Tags: python, testing, python-unittest

Is there a way to get test module names programmatically, from a test suite, when using python unittest?

Python `unittest.loader.TestLoader` has a discover method that returns all test modules but I can't figure out a way to get only the test modules names.

What I did:

```
import TestLoader
suite = loader.discover('path/to/tests')
for test_suite in suite:
    print(test_suite.__module__)
```

This results in:

```
unittest.suite
unittest.suite
unittest.suite
unittest.suite
```

Comment: What about `test_case.id()` ? That gives you "the module and class name" - you might just need to split it on `.` to break out the module from the class name. https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.id

Comment: This doesn't work because `TestLoader` returns `unittest.suite.TestSuite` instances and there is not an `id` method for it.

Comment: Please show a proper [mre]; `TestLoader` cannot be imported as-is (did you mean `from unittest.suite import TestLoader`?), and this code does not define `loader`. Also, if it is returning `TestSuite` instances, then it is not returning modules - please explain the situation (and the results of your debugging) clearly. Finally, the `__module__` attribute of a callable *does* give the name of the module it's defined in. It just happens that each `test_suite` is an instance of the internal representation of tests, not of the underlying class implementing the test logic.

Comment: "This doesn't work because `TestLoader` returns `unittest.suite.TestSuite` instances and there is not an `id` method for it." - okay, so. The *purpose of* a `TestSuite` is to contain `TestCase`s, right? Do you understand how to find the `TestCase`s that are in a given `TestSuite`? (If not, did you try reading the documentation)? If you iterate over the cases in each suite, and get "the module and class name" for each test case, does that solve the problem? If not, why not? Do you understand why a `TestSuite` might not have a specific, single module that implements its tests?

Answer (score 0):

#### Use the dictionary `sys.modules`

You can import the package `sys` and use the dictionary `sys.modules` as in the following code.

File `project/run_all.py`

```
import sys
from unittest.loader import TestLoader

TEST_PREFIX="test"

suite = TestLoader().discover('my_tests', pattern=TEST_PREFIX+"*.py")

for module_name in sys.modules.keys():
    if module_name.startswith(TEST_PREFIX):
        print(module_name)
```

In my example I suppose that the test modules are stored in the folder `project/my_tests` while `run_all.py` is stored in the folder `project`.

So for a tree as following:

```
project
 |-run_all.py
 |-my_tests
   |-test01.py
   |-test02.py
   |-test03.py
```

The output of the execution of `run_all.py` is:

```
path/to/project> python run_all.py
test02
test01
test03
```

#### The argument `pattern`

I have supposed that all my test files have `test` as prefix name (see the variable `TEST_PREFIX="test"`). So I have set the argument `pattern` of the method `discover` to `"test*.py"` (its default value). I hope that this constraint is acceptable.
I made this choice because the dictionary `sys.modules` contains all the name of the modules available for the script `run_all.py`, so establishing a prefix avoids selecting files that are not test files.

Comment: This assumes nothing has imported a module whose name starts with `test`...

Answer (score 0):

You can use `inspect.getmodule()` on the test cases, but you'll need a small recursive function to walk through the tree of suites you get from `.discover`:

```
import inspect
import unittest
from unittest import TestLoader

loader = TestLoader()


def walk_tests(suite: unittest.TestSuite):
    for obj in suite:
        if isinstance(obj, unittest.TestSuite):
            yield from walk_tests(obj)
        else:
            yield obj, inspect.getmodule(obj.__class__)


for test, module in walk_tests(loader.discover("./toasts", pattern="*.py")):
    print((test, module))
```

prints (e.g.)

```
(<a.TestStringMethods testMethod=test_upper>, <module 'a' from '/Users/akx/build/so-misc/toasts/a.py'>)
(<b.TestStringMethods2 testMethod=test_lower>, <module 'b' from '/Users/akx/build/so-misc/toasts/b.py'>)
```